# Android pick and crop image with Huawei

Tags: android, image, crop, huawei-mobile-services

in my app i let the user select an image and crop it afterwards. After this the image is set to an imageView.

I didnt have any problems with my solution until i got a message yesterday from two people with a Huawei smartphone with the same Problem. They always receive a message "Failed to load image..." and there is no image set to the imageView.

While debuging i recogized that data.getData() is null in onActivityResult for the crop intent.

I have tried a lot of different possibilities to pick and crop image and all of them worked for me but none for the Huawei smartphone. I am out of ideas and could need some help.

Here is the code:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Permissions.verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            this.performCrop(uri);

        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP_IMG) {
            if (data != null) {
                ImageView imgView = 
                 (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_my_profile);
                imgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
            }


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.global_default_error),     Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}

private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_my_profile);
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", imgView.getWidth());
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", imgView.getHeight());
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", imgView.getWidth());
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", imgView.getHeight());
        String folder_main = "Test";

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), folder_main);
        f.mkdirs();
        f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()+"/Test/profilepic" + System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg");
        Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, newUri);

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP_IMG);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_my_profile);
        imgView.setImageURI(picUri);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with one of the libraries now =)

Comment: @babaum Can you please share that library link